# Paypal Express Checkout fields dont return values

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have the paypal express checkout api running in the sandbox and i'm able to successfully do a transaction and capture the payment. Now I want to store some values in the database. I can get the transactionID, ordertime, payment status from the resArray no problem. But when I try to add additional variables that are listed on the "DoExpressCheckoutPaymentAPI Operation page of the https://cms.paypal.com website, they don't return any value

I correctly send via doExpresscheckout values for the following

```
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SOFTDESCRIPTOR = 'My Company Name'
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ALLOWEDPAYMENTMETHOD = 'Instant Payment Only'
```

I need to get the value of those as well as 
    PAYMENTINFO_0_SETTLEAMT

But when i read the resArray returned by DoExpressCheckout, these fields are non-existent.

Is there some way to get these values?
 - is settleamt only returned if there is a currency conversion and if not it's not in the returned array?

Also, is there another way to only accept Instant Payments? I can live without the other stuff but I need to set Instant Payments only.

Answer (score 0):

The response is not going to contain everything you pass into the request.  Anything you're passing into the request you already  have, so if you need to store that data you'll just need to do that using the same values you're passing into the request, be it session data or whatever.

You can refer to page 105 of the [PayPal NVP Documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide.pdf) for details on exactly what you should expect back in the DoExpressCheckout response.